# Como enviar apenas uma linha de um array multidimensional para uma function?

Tags: delphi, funções, array-multidimensional

Preciso enviar apenas uma linha de um *array* multidimensional como parâmetro de uma *function*, sem que seja necessário transferir esta linha para outro *array*.

por exemplo:

chamada:

```
var
  UmArray : array [0..4, 0..20] of integer;
begin
//preenche o array

funcao(UmArray[2]);
end;


funcao(UmArray: array of integer);
begin
//faz algo
end;
```

Comment: `array[0]` representa um inteiro por isso declare a função de forma a que receba um inteiro como parâmetro.

Comment: Na verdade, array[0], representa uma linha de uma matriz, e é isso que eu quero passar, um array contendo apenas 1 linha do array multidimensional.

Comment: Desculpe, li mal a pergunta.